Logger/os_log length limitation
Tried to print a long array to console using Logger. I noticed that some entities are missing. Realized that this is due to the fact that the logger message is cut with <…>at the end.
There's no info about os_log length limit in the official reference. However I found a post by Eskimo that mentions that it's limited to 1kb:

NSLog is layered on top of unified logging which has a limit on the
length of the dynamic content in any given log entry (1024 bytes if I
recall correctly).

How would you approach printing longer message to the console? Do not recommend print since it only works with Xcode debugger.

Log several shorter messages ‍♂️

@Cy-4AH, how then whould you read them as a single message? Let's say you log a bad HTTP response, which is a long string, and then you see a part of it. How would you know that you need to look for another part? Some kind of "" at the end?

You might consider just using the “activity ID” feature to associate a series of logging messages  together.

I experimentally verified that it appears to be limited to just under 1kb. And it is not just the Console app, but also command line rendition of log capture/log show, too. But the Xcode console does not suffer this limitation.
If you really needed more than 1kb, you can break it into separate logging messages.
For example, consider:
import os.log

class ApiManager {
    private let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "ApiManager")

    func perform(_ url: URL) async throws {
        logger.info("\(#function, privacy: .public): \(url, privacy: .public)")
        logger.error("Line 1")
        logger.error("Line 2")
        logger.error("Line 3")
    }
}

FWIW, as a matter of practice, I always use a “category” associated with the subsystem/type doing the logging. Below, I am filtering on that category to reduce the noise in the console. I also generally filter on the “subsystem”, too.
Then, when viewing it in the console, you can right-click on a message and choose “Show Activity ID”. For example, I've started by filtering the console for messages from my “ApiManager” category. Seeing three sets of errors, I can right click on one of the and choose “Show Activity ID” and I see just the messages associated with that particular activity. Having narrowed it down to a given activity, I can then remove the “ApiManager” filter, and I see a more complete list of messages associated with that activity, putting my logging messages in a broader context (in my case, the fact that it was initiated from some button click):


Obviously, you can also just write the messages to your own text file. And if this is running on a device, the next time you connect to Xcode, you can use the “Devices and Simulators” window, select your app, and click on the “…” button, and choose “Download Container…”, and find this file in that container.

This is a bit of an edge-case, but this is especially useful for not only large messages, but also debugging processes that take a lot of time. E.g., when trying to test background tasks (like location manager, push notification, etc.) over a very long time (days, weeks, months, etc.), this technique really excels. Anyway, it is another option. Just remember to remove this sort of logging in production apps.
The deeper question is whether huge messages belong in the Console at all. It's been optimized for size (it is compressed) and recording speed (though retrieval speed, when reviewing the results, can be very slow). Maybe these large “payload” related events should go elsewhere.

Thanks! Maybe you also have a solution for auto-splitting of long messages?

Probably lots of ways to skin the cat, but perhaps https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/d7eadeec08b573c5add9727645897e0e.
